# Local Blobstore fails when converting the form into jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine

I've used the blobstore approach with JAVA GAE in a regular form submission

```
<form id="myform" action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/saveform") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="logo" name="logo"/>
```

When I submit the form, it works as expected. The image is saved to the blobstore and i have the key/url.

When I try to turn this form into an ajax form, by adding the following It fails.

```
$.ajax({
  'type' : 'POST',
  'url' : $("#myform").attr('action'), 
  'data': $("#myform").serialize()})
.done(function (msg){
  if (msg!="1") {
    $("#errors").empty().append("<p class='error'>" + msg + "</p>");
    return false;
  }
});
```

I get the following error in the console.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Java heap space) http:///_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgnDA

And in eclipse I get
WARNING: Error for /_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgnDA
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Any suggestions?

Comment: `http:///`_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgnDA looks like the issue. When the DOM load, what does `action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/saveform") %>"` print?

Comment: Sorry.. stackoverflow doens't allow for "localhost" urls, so i just removed it.
It looks like http://!localhost!:8888/_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgqDA

Answer (score 3):

It is because of you are sending the data as  $("#myform").serialize(), which creates the problem. In this case, your contentType is not 'multipart/form-data', it is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead.. You have to use something like following...

```
$.ajax({
   url : blobUrl,
   type : 'POST',
   cache : false,
   data : new FormData($("#myForm")[0]),
   processData : false,
   contentType : false,
   success : function(data) {
        console.log("Success!!!");
    }
});
```

As blobstore allows the binary data and the content Type in this method will be multipart/form-data,(you can check that in Networks tab in chrome developer console) it will work, Try this.

Hope this helps,
Thanks.